# Is this definition of "preshipped" incorrect?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

Looking at the number of tweets and followers, I had subscribed to a twitter account of ['Vocabulary Builder'](https://twitter.com/Vocabits). It tweets about the words and I try to learn from it.

The word it posted today is...

> [Preshipped](https://twitter.com/Vocabits/status/505500561953665024) (noun) - *Large vessel for navigating in water*

Though the word does not seem to be popular, Collin's definition is all different for that word **(And I agree with this)** -

> preshipped (adjective) - *relating to items sent ahead of time*

Kindly clarify this to me.

Comment: It's exactly the meaning of 'Ship' : " Large vessel for navigating in water". It seems to be a typo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the limitations of software-created definitions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, C'mon - my answer is about dodgy software (or a dodgy person) the question wasn't.

Comment: @Frank: Your answer may be "correct", but the fact of the matter is there wouldn't be a question at all if it weren't for the "dodgy software/speaker" aspect. So the question isn't really about *English* - it's about *crappy software*.

Comment: @Fumble - This question is about the meaning of _preshipped_. Crappy software may be the reason for the misunderstanding, but it's not the subject of this question.

Comment: @Frank never mind the ' close' appeal. I got a good answer. As for FF, s/he's fond of hitting close button than answering as I see that in most of my questions. ;)

Comment: The question is completely stupid. The word **preship** isn't even recognised by OED, but on the rare occasion anyone encountered [a need for] it, the meaning of the ad-hoc word would be clear. A discussion about the merits of OP's source is Off Topic, and the reason **preshipped** isn't in dictionaries is because there's *hardly any need for it, and the meaning is obvious in any feasible context anyway*.

Comment: @Fumble - This question was prompted by someone trying to improve their English by using a program called Vocabulary Builder, which gave erroneous information. It seems like the O.P. already had doubts about the reliability of the program, but wanted to double-check. ELL was designed to give learners a place to ask a question about English without people coming along and saying, "This question is completely stupid." For the native, perhaps; for the learner, maybe not so much. I'd upvote your last comment on ELU, but, here on ELL, I find that attitude irritatingly condescending.

Comment: @J.R.: Just because learners don't know English very well doesn't mean they're idiots. This particular OP is quite capable of understanding the ***pre-*** prefix and ***-ed*** suffix, and interpreting them in the context of the *verb* "to ship" (as evidenced by the fact that he agrees with that rather unusual definition in Collins). I stand by my closevote, but I accept there's little chance either of us will be changing our opinions on this matter.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - What do you find unusual about the definition in Collins? By the way, I have no problem with you standing by your closevote (we have the right to agree to disagree), but I'd ask that you'd be more careful before you leave comments that deem questions "completely stupid" – that's **not** _playing nice._

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should thank Frank first for the homework he did. Without his input, you could have *never* gotten the 'closing reason' in your gray matter!

Comment: @J.R.: I find it "odd" that Collins should have a definition at all. The only answer that currently has any upvotes doesn't even bother to mention the "meaning" of the word, and clearly the OP doesn't need the definition anyway. I honestly can't see anything here apart from "don't trust automated language acquisition tools" - which if it's relevant to ELL at all, it a "meta" question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are quite correct. I should also have included some further information about _preshipped_ rather than only focusing on the 'wrong' definition. I didn't bother because the Collins definition fits exactly with what I understand _pre+ship[p]+ed_ to mean. I've updated with some links to the earliest valid mentions that I can find in Google Books, a link to the most recent reference and a short summary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks rather like that Twitter feed is using Dictionary.com as it's source (with some adjustment to the actual text).

Sadly, Dictionary.com 'auto-finds' the nearest word it knows to that which you type.

If you type *preshipped* you get the definition for *ship*. The first entry for *ship* is for the noun *ship* (as you'd expect) and the wording is almost exactly the same.

I checked a couple of others near *preshipped*. Some of them have slightly altered wording but it's clear dictionary.com is the source.

- *Quasinormal* gives the definition for *normal*
- *Halfaquiescent* gives the definition for *aquiescent*
- *Digressionary* gives the definition for *digression*

> All in all I'd suggest that you should not trust the definition from
> 'Vocabulary Builder' until after checking the definition at Dictionary.com, unless you want your vocabulary to be large, but
> substantially wrong.
> I guess it is an OK source for new words, it's just that the definitions might not be correct.
>
> Dictionary.com definitions are trustworthy, the definitions 'Vocabularly Builder' chooses out of the choice given at Dictionary.com for a word are most certainly not trustworthy.

**Edit (for *preshipped*)**

As noted in the question, *preshipped* is defined in the Collins dictionary but that appears to be the only on-line definition of the word. Much of OED2 and OED on-line is exactly as it was in OED1 and has not been updated since OED1. As a related example, OED2 has only a single mention of *airfreight* and that is in one of it's examples of usage for the word *freight*. The definition of *airfreight* can be found in many on-line dictionaries.

The first mention of *preshipped* that I can find in Google Books is from 1943 (there are earlier references suggested but they are incorrect) in a report from the [US Armed Forces regarding *preshipment* of materials](http://books.google.com/books?id=BB4ZAQAAIAAJ&q=%22preshipped%22&dq=%22preshipped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tRcEVICeGsH38QWW8ICYCw&redir_esc=y).

There are a few mentions in a logistics report, [United States Army in World War II Global Logistics and Strategy, Robert W. Coakley](http://books.google.com/books?id=o9NWAAAAYAAJ&q=%22preshipped%22&dq=%22preshipped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tRcEVICeGsH38QWW8ICYCw&redir_esc=y)  and these seem to suggest that the word is being used to mean *shipped before a need [for the equipment] has been properly identified, based on an assumption that there might/will be a need in the future*.

When *preshipped* was in it's infancy, early 1940's, it was used in a military sense particularly by the US Armed Forces (and US Congress when discussing it). There's a nice mention of it here in the [Department of the Army technical manual
Operators, Organizational, Direct Support, General Support and Depot Maintenance Manual Including Repair Parts and Special Tool Lists: Teletypewriter Terminal AN/MGC-22,, United States. Dept. of the Army](http://books.google.com/books?id=mcwXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP8&dq=%22preshipped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6B8EVOLvKInp8AXr6IKwDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22preshipped%22&f=false) where there is a distinction made between *preshipped* and *requisitioned*.

Late 20th and early 21st century examples are not limited to military use, although that is still the major usage; modern usage covers software distribution, personal belongings being shipped to a destination before the owner, meat samples *preshipped* before the full delivery etc. etc.

The most recent usage I could find harks back to the 1943 usage of *ship something in the expectation that it will be needed in the future* and describes (the on-line retailer) Amazon's new *anticipatory shipping* technique; you can find it in [this article at TechCrunch.com](http://techcrunch.com/2014/01/18/amazon-pre-ships/).

Summary :
*preshipped* appears to be a term used initially in the field of US Armed Forces logistics since the early 1940's. It now appears to be gaining more widespread use. Given time, it is bound to appear in more dictionaries as they are updated.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I think your conclusion is a bit harsh. My recommendation would be that folks using VB should take their tweets [with a grain of salt](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/take-with-a-grain-of-salt.html).

Comment: This is the third such instance I remember of VB. Every time, I retweet mentioning the error but they never respond. I am pretty sure, the posting is through some tailor-made software. Anyway... 'Unfollowed' ;)

Comment: @J.R. I've lightened up a little, making it clearer that Dictionary.com is NOT wrong.

Comment: Gaffes like the one the O.P. highlighted here do teach a valuable lesson about English. Many English words – like *ship* – function as both verbs and nouns (e.g., *air, bet, cough, doubt, echo, find, grease, heat, ink*, and *jolt*, to name a few). If poorly-designed software grabs an entry out of the dictionary, it could easily grab the meaning of the noun when the word form demands the meaning of the verb. This might also explain why rudimentary translation software often does such a bad job of translating short phrases.

Answer (score 0):

> Preshipped (noun) - Large vessel for navigating in water

This is wrong. Just wrong.

> preshipped (adjective) - relating to items sent ahead of time

Don't learn whole-words like this. Break it down and the meaning is clear. That's how I was taught back in grade 3.

Pre- : to do before

Ship :

- (noun) - Large vessel for navigating in water
- (verb) - To transport something at reasonable cost and speed

-ed : past-tense suffix. Or passive form.

So, preshipped means the item was sent before it was needed / ordered, and maybe it was sent in the past. (the other meaning doesn't make any sense)

Why? If someone makes a product with known demand but very important (or very slow) delivery times they may send it expecting future sales.

"We preshipped the iPhone 6 to dealers last week."

"Winter tires are preshipped in September"

Comment: Just a nit- but where did you get that definition for *ship* (v)?  I don't think reasonable cost and speed enters into it.  Every time I ship something I pay too much and it takes too long, but I ship it anyway.

Comment: I agree with @Jim - the approach here is good, but the example definition of ship (v) is clearly in error. To _ship_ means [to transport by air, train, boat, or truck](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/ship); cost has little to do with it, and reasonableness even less so. The word _ship_ can be defined in [many different ways](http://www.onelook.com/?w=ship), but I can't find any dictionary definition that even mentions cost.

Comment: If I want it there quickly I say "courier". There's a huge difference between 2nd-class mail, FedEX and hiring your own aircraft. If it absolutely, positively has to be in Frankfurt in 24 hours we usually don't say "ship this box to Frankfurt".

Comment: @paul - What word would you use instead? Do you really use _courier_ as a verb?

Comment: @paul you can definitely say that you want something shipped by a courier, or shipped by hiring your own aircraft - for example, http://www.macrumors.com/2013/09/11/how-apple-ships-millions-of-iphones-for-simultaneous-delivery/ article about such a case would correctly use the verb 'ship'. A heading 'Apple couriers millions of iPhones' would sound blatantly wrong to me, though it might be okay for other uses. In any case, shipped is a more general form - it can be used also for deliveries of unreasonable cost and extreme speed.