# expect to & expect?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> If it's four o'clock in the morning, don't expect to them to be pleased to see you.

This is a sentence from Collins Cobuild English Grammar. Is it natural? Why there is a "to" after “expect“? I think “If it's four o'clock in the morning, don't expect them to be pleased to see you." is more natural. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, if your transcription is accurate that's mistake in the book.

Comment: I'm not convinced this should be closed.  OP is not basing a question on a bad premise due to a misprint, the question is asking whether it is or is not correct. In my opinion this is just as valid a question as any other question asking about grammar validity.

Comment: @Jim not at all! We do close such sensible question here. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/is-this-definition-of-preshipped-incorrect :) I'm not sure how to bring **that** *off topic* sentence here after clicking the 'close' link. And good observation, April. +1

Answer (score 2):

The quote from the book is incorrect.

The correct form would be:

```
If it's four o'clock in the morning, don't expect them to be pleased to see you.
```

This confirms the larger point of not relying on prepared materials when learning a new language.  You need to have a native speaker(or group, as you have here.)  There are many materials for language learning that are incorrect or outdated such as the Pimsleur language series that still teaches 100+ year-old grammar and vocabulary rules in the majority of their recordings.